# Parsing a text file with a single record over multiple lines and placeholders for fields spanning multiple lines

Tags: c#, parsing

I have an exported data file which is very similar to a CSV format file except for a few quirks with the fields spanning multiple lines.

An Example format (of a single record) of this file would be

```
ID, email, Email_Body, Email_Subject, Count, Created_Date, User<CR>
648847,"hello@gmail.com",$long,$long,1,2020-01-15-04.47.56.558000,"Adam",<CR>
//<CR>
Hello~<CR>
How are you?~<CR>
//<CR>
The Email Subject~<CR>
//<CR>
```

The "$long" indicates this field is a comment field and the val;ue for it will be on the next line(s)
The value delimiter is "," and row delimiter is a  carriage return
The "//" indicates the start and end of the comment field and the "~" at the end of the comment field row indicates that row is part of the comment.

I have been able to write a fairly simple C# parser using ReadAllLines and iterating through each row to detect the number of "$long" fields and then using the "//" to detect the start and end of a multi line text value. However with a text file with ~500,000 rows, this parser is taking around 2 hours to run so I am looking at alternative ways to parse the text or improve the efficiency of the parser.

The current code

```
private void lineByLine(string path)
{
    int numComments = 0;
    int numCommas = 0;
    int startLine = 0;
    string output = "";
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
    for (int x = 0; x < lines.Count(); x++)
    {
        string s = lines[x];
        if (s.StartsWith("$DATATYPES"))
        {
            // count number of commas
            numCommas = Regex.Matches(s, ",").Count;

            // count number of '$long' on the next line (which should be the first real row)
            numComments = Regex.Matches(lines[x + 1], "\\$long").Count;

            // start from here next time:
            startLine = x;
            break;
        }
    }

    List<int> datalines = new List<int>();
    for (int x = startLine + 1; x < lines.Count(); x++) // add +1 to the start so we don't get the definition row
    {
        if (lines[x].Split(',').Count() >= numCommas)
        {
            if (Regex.Matches(lines[x], "\\$long").Count == numComments) // had to add this check as well as some comments had lots of commas 
            {
                datalines.Add(x);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < datalines.Count(); x++)
    {
        string currentLine = lines[datalines[x]];


        string commentsText = "";
        if (x == datalines.Count() - 1)
        {
            for (int y = x + 1; y < lines.Count(); y++)
            {
                commentsText += lines[y];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int test1 = datalines[x] + 1;
            int test2 = datalines[x + 1];
            for (int y = datalines[x] + 1; y < datalines[x + 1]; y++)
            {
                commentsText += lines[y];
            }
        }

        commentsText.Replace("/r", "");
        string[] comments = commentsText.Split(new string[] { "//" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        if (comments.Count() != numComments)
        {
            ("error - incorrect number of comments found").Dump();
            ("expecting " + numComments + " comments").Dump();
            ("found " + comments.Count() + " comments").Dump();
            
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < numComments; y++)
        {
            currentLine = ReplaceFirst(currentLine, "$long", comments[y]);
        }

        output += currentLine + Environment.NewLine;
    }


}

public string ReplaceFirst(string text, string search, string replace)
{
    int pos = text.IndexOf(search);
    if (pos < 0)
    {
        return text;
    }
    return text.Substring(0, pos) + replace + text.Substring(pos + search.Length);
}
```

Comment: Its likely your code is extremely inefficient, but you haven't shown any, i guess you are just looking for replacement code (which is not really in the spirit of what stackoverflow is about). Consider pasting the code you have

Comment: @MichaelRandall I wasn't expecting replacement code, but potentially another methodology for approaching this problem, either via a library that can handle this or insight into what has worked in the past.

Comment: Open Task Manager and see how much memory your code is using while running.  Most Likely you are using over 100% of the memory and the excess memory is being put into swap space which is on your hard driver (and very slow).  Regex uses lots of memory and is not the right tool to use.  Read the file one line at a time so you do not use so much memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON this is ez and fast
for more information see [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to) or [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

> The Json.NET is faster and more comfortable than System.Text.Json